# Transformar una lista a una frase

Tags: python

Hola quería reemplazar cada espacio en una lista por un carácter e imprimirlo sin que se vean los corchetes al final pero el resultado no me gusto y no supe sin solucionarlo sin usar `.join()`

```
a = list(input("Que frase quieres: \n"))
x = input("Intruduce caracter: ")

def cambiar(a, x):
    for i in a:
        if i == " ":
            d = a.index(" ")
            a.insert(d, x)
            a.remove(" ")
    return a

l = cambiar(a, x)
print(*l)
```

intento no usar el `.join()`, y quería saber si se podía "juntar" toda esa lista para dejarlo mas como si fuera un print que como si estuviera imprimiendo una lista intente con el `*` pero tampoco quedo como si fuera un `print()`

Comment: osea quieres crear tu propio `join`?

Comment: Buen día, ¿Es necesario utilizar la lista en el input? ¿O únicamente quieres reemplazar los espacios por X caracter e imprimirlo? ¿Cuál es el propósito del ejercicio? ¿Necesitas crear una función?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Si únicamente quieres imprimir la misma frase pero cambiando los espacios por "X" caracter entonces puedes utilizar el argumento `sep` (Separador) de `print()`

Al leer la frase inicial la separas cada vez que haya un espacio con `split()` y luego imprimes cambiando el separador por el caracter que el usuario ingrese

```
a = input("Que frase quieres: \n").split()
x = input("Intruduce caracter: ")

print(*a, sep=x)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
Que frase quieres: 
 Una frase cualquiera
Intruduce caracter:  -
Una-frase-cualquiera
```

Si deseas crear la lista y luego utilizar tu función e imprimirla sin que `print()` te agregue espacios entre letras entonces puedes utilizar `sep=''`

```
a = list(input("Que frase quieres: \n"))
x = input("Intruduce caracter: ")

def cambiar(a, x):
    for i in a:
        if i == " ":
            d = a.index(" ")
            a.insert(d, x)
            a.remove(" ")
    return a

l = cambiar(a, x)
print(*l, sep='')
```

Esto devuelve:

```
Que frase quieres: 
 Una frase cualquiera
Intruduce caracter:  -
Una-frase-cualquiera
```